# jQuery UI datepicker css customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Let's say I want to display a datepicker. This datepicker represents a disponibility calendar from an hotel room. Knowing this, I want before displaying fetch data from the server to know the disponibility (I know how to do this).

My question is: How can I change the css to show dates with disponibility different from the ones that doesn't have?.

Second Question: How can I disable clicking those ones that doesn't have rooms available.

Example: [JetSetter calendar](http://www.jetsetter.com/sale/essexresortvt2/essexresort?nm=splash&cl=0)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this page to disable the days you want :

http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

Comment: the example in the page is not working http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-datepicker.php